# Object not Rotating Correctly?

Tags: animation

bit of a noob here. I'm trying to learn 3D, and just did Blender Guru's donut tutorial. I wanted to do a little video with my donut where it rolls forward and crushes the camera. But, whenever I rotate the donut, it gets all wobbly. It moves forward straight, but the rotation is off. It ends at the rotation that I set it to, but the rotation path is all over the place. I tried to put some pictures to show what I mean. I've tried changing the axis it rotates on from global to local, locking the other directions and just letting the correct axis values change, I followed some rolling tire tutorials that use constraints and an empty box (like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DuzdO5ENAvY&t=197s) but I just can't get it to work. Any advice?

[image]

[[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, have you applied the rotation? or please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/